# Reading from a MYSQL table every 5 seconds and dynamically displaying results on a PHP page without refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm looking to display data from a table in a mysql database using PHP, however, I want the data to automatically update itself and retrieve current values every 5 seconds.. WITHOUT having to refresh the page. Is this possible? Maybe with JQuery/ AJAX? If so, please explain how it can be done / point me to a resource where I can find such information

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can easy implement it with JQuery/ AJAX

Comment: @normanram are you trying to do instant messaging from a database?

Comment: Yes, just send request to your php script every 5 seconds using jquery.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @dqhendricks, no, i'm making a dashboard where the data must be (as close as possible to) real time

Comment: @Alex this refreshes the DIV, but will not pull new information from the database.

Comment: @normanram The very first result shows you exactly how to do what you seek. The response.php script noted in the example is the server-side code that grabs the latest data and formats it. The jquery script then simply runs it every X seconds.

Comment: @normanram - If you make a small PHP script that returns what you need updated by pulling it from the database and formatting it as HTML, you can use my example below. It's quite simple and should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) and jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you should be able to do what you want. The PHP script should return the HTML that needs to replace the previous one.

**Javascript:**

```
function refreshData()
{
  // Load the content of "path/to/script.php" into an element with ID "#container".
  $('#container').load('path/to/script.php');
}

// Execute every 5 seconds
window.setInterval(refreshData, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

A really basic example:

```
  function poll(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "GET", 
           url: "your/php/script/",
           success: function(data){
              // do something with data
           }

       });
   };
   setInterval(poll, 5000);
```

Comment: While `.ajax()` offers a lot of flexibility, wouldn't be better to just use `.load()` as in my answer instead since he's looking to replace parts of his dashboard with updated data?

Comment: @Francois Deschenes - Well it kind of depends on what you're loading I guess. The question didn't specify the exact usage, so I went for the $.ajax option if for some reason he wanted to load more than just plain text/html, say, loading JSON to fill a table or something for example.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a good option. [Here  are the docs for ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You will want to make this call with [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Something like this might get your started.

```
setIntervla(updateFromDb,5000);

function updateFromDb(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "getUpdates.php",
     success: function(){
     $(this).addClass("done");
     }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is exactly the type of the AJAX is used for, AJAX allows for asynchronous requests to be made to your server.

For learning I would suggest using a framework like [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and look into the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) api.

Basicly you will need a PHP script that query the database and responds the results the way you want them. A suggestion would be to [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) encode them.

In JavaScript on the client you will need to you things like:

```
var poll = setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url: "yourpage.php",
     success: function(data){
        //HANDLE DATA
        // use JSON.parse(data); if your JSON encoding your data  
    }
   });
},5000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the documentation of jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Use the command "jQuery.get()" or better "jQuery.getJson()" to make a http request to the server. Use JSON to get a better communication between server and client. Return from server side a json string and convert this on the client to an javascript object. (the function jQuery.getJson already do this for you) so you can easily access the key and values in the data array.

Just an example:

SERVER Part with PHP:

```
<?

$data = array('key'=>'value');
return json_encode($data, true);
```

CLIENT Part:

```
$.getJSON('myurl.php', function(data) {
    // THIS ONE IS CALLED with your PHP data
    alert(data.key);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.post("filename.php",{'field1':field1,'field2':field2,'field3':field3},function(data){
    //callbackfunction(data)
})
},30000);//millisecs
```

});

And have your php file do all your sql